# Replacing NULL in a column with the latest data from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a main query below that I am using to join data from table 2 on person # (unique column), as well as year and month to bring in user name id, GL_ENTITY  and GL_ENTITY_DESC for each month and year in the row.

The problem table 2 has missing data for some months and year so I am getting null for some person # for particular month and year so I am getting the result below:

```
| EF.PERSON# | EF.Month | EF.Year | C.USERNAME_ID | C.GL_ENTITY_CD | C.GL_ENTITY_DESC|
|------------+----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------|
|     101    |    Jan   |   2020  |     user101   |      1         |      finance    |
|     102    |    Feb   |   2020  |      NULL     |     NULL       |       NULL      |
|     101    |    Mar   |   2020  |      NULL     |     NULL       |       NULL      |



SELECT 
    ,EF.[Month]
    ,EF.[Year]
    ,EF.[PERSON#]
    ,Convert(DATE, EF.[Month] + ' ' + str(EF.[Year])) AS [Month date]
    ,c.[USERNAME_ID]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_CD] AS [NDW-GL Entity]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC] AS [NDW-GL Entity Desc]
FROM [Table 1] EF
LEFT JOIN [TABLE 2] c ON EF.[Year] = c.[yr]
    AND EF.[Month] = c.[MTH]
    AND EF.[PERSON#] = c.[PERSON#_NUM]
```

For the null data for above, I am looking to do is get the max data from table 2  for the max month, year and person #  and vlook up those into the null values for  C.USERNAME_ID , C.GL_ENTITY_CD, C.GL_ENTITY_DESC

my table 2 is setup as following:

```
| year | month | person #_num | username_id | gl_entity_cd | gl_entity_desc |
|------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------|
| 2019 |  dec  |      102     |   user102   |      1       |      sales     |
| 2020 |  jan  |      101     |    user1    |      1       |     finance    | 
...ect
```

I have created this subquery below which brings in the latest and max entry based on person # for their latest month and year which I would like to replace the nulls in main query with:

```
(SELECT distinct MX.USERNAME_ID as [MAX Username]
,MX.[GL_ENTITY_CD]
,MX.GL_ENTITY_DESC
,t.[PERSON#]
FROM (
SELECT 
    [Month]
    ,[Year]
    ,Convert(DATE, [Month] + ' ' + str([Year])) AS [Month date]
    ,[PERSON#]
    ,c.[USERNAME_ID]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_CD] AS [NDW-GL Entity]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC] AS [NDW-GL Entity Desc]
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Table 1]
LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] c ON [Year] = c.[yr]
    AND [Month] = c.[MTH]
    AND [PERSON#] = c.[PERSON#_NUM]
) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT (Convert(DATE, A.[mth] + ' ' + str(A.[yr]))) AS [Max date]
    ,a.*
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT B.[PERSON#_NUM]
            ,max(Convert(DATE, B.[mth] + ' ' + str(B.[yr]))) AS [max date]
        FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] B
        WHERE A.[PERSON#_NUM] = B.[PERSON#_NUM]
        GROUP BY B.[PERSON#_NUM]
        HAVING (Convert(DATE, A.[mth] + ' ' + str(A.[yr]))) = max(Convert(DATE, B.[mth] + ' ' + str(B.[yr])))
        )
) AS MX ON T.[PERSON#] = MX.[PERSON#_NUM]

WHERE t.[USERNAME_ID] IS NULL
 )
```

The result is query with the max record for a person # where there is null in the user name:

```
| MAX NT_login | person # | GL_ENTITY_CD | GL_ENTITY_DESC |
|--------------+----------+--------------+----------------|
|    user101   |    101   |       1      |     sales      |
|    user102   |    102   |       1      |     sales      |
...ect
```

The problem I am having now is how do I replace the NULLS in my main query with the the max results for C.USERNAME_ID  from subquery table while keeping the records existing the same?

I tried case statement but not sure how to incorporate the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend changing a lot of your column names, storing months as numbers, and more.

But without getting into those things, for your specific question, I recommend using `row_number()` to order your 'table 2' records by user based on the month and year.

Then reference that table twice in your main query.  The first reference will be the regular left-joining based on user and month that you're already doing.  The second one will only relate based on user, and will only consider the most recent.

Then in your select statement you use 'isnull()' to first consider the date-level record if it's available, and the user-level record if it's not.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#c') is not null
    drop table #c;

select      *,
            recency = row_number() over(
                partition by [person#_num] 
                order by convert(date, mth + ' ' + str(yr)) desc
            )
into        #c
from        [table 2]; 

select      EF.[Month],
            EF.[Year],
            EF.[PERSON#],
            [Month date] = convert(date, ef.[month] + ' ' + str(ef.[year])),
            username_id = isnull(c.username_id, cRecent.username_id),
            [NDW-GL Entity] = isnull(c.gl_entity_cd, cRecent.gl_entity_cd),
            [NDW-GL Entity Desc] = isnull(c.gl_entity_desc, cRecent.gl_entity_desc)
from        [table 1] ef
left join   #c as c 
                on ef.[year] = c.[yr]
                and ef.[month] = c.[mth]
                and ef.[person#] = c.[person#_num]
left join   #c as cRecent
                on ef.[person#] = cRecent.[person#_num]
                and crecent.recency = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. but is there a way to redo this query with out the With clause as i cant seem to create a temp table out from it.

also if you dont mind, i see you approach is a lot different but easier than what i did above.. was there a way i could have made my query work with the nested temp table i made?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on your need.  Are you saying you desire the final output to be inserted into a temp table?  If so, I can link you a resource with an example of how it works with a 'with' query.  Or are you saying you really want the with-clause contents in a temp table?  If so, I suppose I can help you, but why do you want this?  I also wonder if you're confusing the term 'temp table' with 'subquery'.  And if you mean subquery, then I ask again, why subquery instead of 'with' clause?  Are you working in an old version without that feature?

Comment: I'll go ahead and edit my response to output the 'with' clause contents into a temp table first, and use the temp table, just in case you want that for performance issues.  But I can't help but think you're just shy of the feature.  At any rate, stand by for the edit.

Comment: Thank you. i am working in sql 2012 so with  clause seems to have it limits  on what i can do and not do so it wouldn't allow me to use this query with the with clause. how ever, i was able to edit the query by creating sub queries out of the joins and labeling them as c and and c recent and that seemed to work. but the above works as well

Comment: 1 more thing, so my  [NDW-GL Entity Desc]  is in table 1 and table 2 both. in the query above, you bring the field from table two with the latest records if there is a null that exist with  [NDW-GL Entity Desc] = isnull(c.gl_entity_desc, cRecent.gl_entity_desc). 

suppose i want to go one step further, some of the records for the [NDW-GL Entity Desc] = isnull(c.gl_entity_desc, cRecent.gl_entity_desc) line above are showing as 0.

but table 1 has them showing as the right field, what will i need to do so for anything showing 0 or something else bring the data from EF. [NDW-GL Entity Desc]

Comment: I'm glad my advice helped.  With respect, I think I'm going to have you struggle with your new issue for a bit.  If you still can't get it, go ahead and make a simplified version of the issue and ask it as another question.  But I will say you should look into 'case' statements or the 'coalesce' function.